# How to realloc() memory to string array

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a string array of,

```
char *string_arr[] = {     "Hi",  "Hi2", "Hi3", "Hi4"    };
```

Now I need to realloc memory to the array, because I have to insert another element into the array like "Hi5". How can I do that?

I tried:

```
string_arr = realloc (.....);
```

but it doesn't work, it gives: "incompatible types in assignment" error.

Comment: sizeof (string_arr[0]); doesnt give the right space. other elements are 3 seen chars but zeroth element is 2 seen chars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1) You are attempting to realloc() a fixed-size array.  realloc() can only be used on memory allocated using malloc().

2) string_arr is an array, not a pointer.  Arrays do degenerate into pointers when used as rvalues in expressions, but are still distinct data types as lvalues.

Answer (score 4):

You can only "realloc()" a pointer to memory you got from "malloc ()".

```
char **string_arr;

int nelms = 10;
string_array = (char **)malloc (sizeof (char *) * nelms);
if (!string_array) {
  perror ("malloc failed");
  return;
}

string_array[0] = strdup ("Hi");
string_array[1] = strdup ("Hi2");
string_array[2] = strdup ("Hi3");
string_array[3] = strdup ( "Hi4");
...
string_array = realloc (...);
...
```

Comment: ...or previously returned by a `calloc()` or `realloc()`.

Comment: Hummm... the last line of the code sample above, what happens if `realloc` fails, you've got a memory leak there on `string_array`...

Answer (score 3):

You cannot `realloc` an array that has not been `malloc`-ed.

Answer (score 2):

Memory for the string array will be allocated in read-only section.

```
      .section        .rodata
    .LC0:
            .string "Hi"
    .LC1:
            .string "Hi2"
    .LC2:
            .string "Hi3"
    .LC3:
            .string "Hi4"
            .text
    .globl main
            .type   main, @function
    main:
            pushl   %ebp
            movl    %esp, %ebp
            subl    $16, %esp
            movl    $.LC0, -16(%ebp)
            movl    $.LC1, -12(%ebp)
.....
.....
```

Not in the heap. so you can't use `realloc()` to extend the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array of size +1, transfer the elements from the initial array to the new array.